# Photoshop saves images in a larger size than specified while creating the document

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, size

I realized this when using the Photshop generated A4 sized image as a Word template. Word tells me the image is larger than A4 and I verified this using an online tool as well.

I selected the Photoshop preset A4 layout sized 8.268"x11.693" at 300 resolution. However, the saved image is 25.83"x36.54" (or 2480px x 2508px) which is proportional to the intended size but larger.

- Selected preset: 8.268"x11.693" or 2480px x 3508px
- Final generated size: 25.83"x36.54" or 2480px x 3508px

Could anyone tell me why this is happening and how can I ensure the final size is the same as I select it to be?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Most likely Word doesn't recognise the PPI setting and so is not setting the image to the correct size.  Look at the sizes, they are exactly the same in pixels. I don't know if Word even has this functionality. You could perhaps try scaling it manually in Word to fit the page.  Also note that Word is not graphic design software.

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr. 

The reason I want to have it in the exact size is I could enter 100% width and Word would fit it to screen. Without it I have to manually manipulate the image resulting in imperfection.

Besides an online tool I use too reports the width to the enlarged.

Comment: @BillyKerr is absolutely correct here. The size in pixels is the same for both Photoshop at 300 ppi and your other programs (Word, etc.). These other apps are showing your picture at 96 ppi which is the old "standard" from way back for Windows monitors. The math is 8.268/25.83= 96/300- spot on.

Comment: Math don't work...  Are you certain you don't mean 2480x**3**508px?

Comment: Yes, thank you @Scott. Corrected.